# Calling inner functions in Scala

Tags: function, scala

I am new to Scala and i have to code examples that include an inner function. For example given this function below, I understood that when fib is executed, it immediately executes the last line, i.e fibS(x,0,1), however I do not get when this function will stop since if z is returned, wouldn't the program call fibS(x,0,1) again? Thanks

```
def fib(x: Long ): Long = {
 def fibS(i: Long, z: Long, y: Long): Long = {       
  if (i > 0) 
   fibS(i-1, z+y, z) 
  else z
 }
 fibS(x, 0, 1) 
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect - it does not even compile, because `z` is never defined. I think you meant `x` by `z`.

Comment: I don't quite see the reason for a down vote here...

Answer (score 2):

Defining inner method in Scala is a scope issue, so when you call `fibS` from `fib` then you call a function once, a recursive function, that is hidden from other functions because it is defined inside the `fib` function.

If you move `fibS` outside then you will get the same result.

Comment: so when return z is encountered, the outer method,fib, will be terminated right?

Comment: Yes, when fibS ends fib will return with the result

Answer (score 0):

A small illustrative example. Suppose you have functions `a` and `b` and another `callBoth`.

```
def a = { ... }
def b = { ... }
def callBoth = {
  a;
  b;
}
```

When you call `a` what happens? When you call `b` what happens?

Answer:

- `a` is executed and the program flow continues after `a`.
- `b` is executed and the program flow continues after `b`.
- after `b`, it happens to be the return of `callBoth`, meaning the program flow will continue after whatever called `callBoth`.

The same happen with `fibS`, only that it's a single functional call. In the above example, calling `a` alone won't trigger `b`. So, calling `fibS` returns after its call.